# How is isinstance implemented in Python?

Tags: python, cpython

I know what the `isinstance(inst, cls)` function does in Python, but I cannot seem to understand how it is implemented under the hood in the standard implementation of Python (CPython).

Here's a Python-based function I've made to try to reproduce the functionality of `isinstance`. But I have no idea how it ***actually*** works.

```py
def _isinstance(obj: object, cls: type) -> bool:
    if hasattr(obj, "__instancecheck__") and hasattr(obj.__instancecheck__, "__call__"):
        return obj.__instancecheck__(cls)
    
    if type(obj) is type:
        return cls in (*obj.__mro__, obj.__class__)
    else:
        return cls in obj.__class__.__mro__
```

If you could include a similar `_isinstance` function along with your explanation, I'd be very thankful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [PEP 3119](https://peps.python.org/pep-3119/) which introduced abstract base classes? It includes sample implementations for ```__instancecheck__```. Basically, you traverse the [```class.mro()```](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro) list and compare classes for equality

Comment: @Homer512  I tried that initially, but since `isinstance(object, type)` returns `True`, I thought I must check `obj.__class__`, too. Or is `object`'s `__class__` an exception? That would make sense I guess, because the base class of all classes can't have a base class, and some placeholder value such as `None` as a value to the `__class__` attribute would be quite unpythonic

Comment: **Update**: Just found out the `type` type has its own `__instancecheck__`. It should be possible to check if the object is a class, and otherwise, reassign `obj`'s `__class__` to itself. This should be done to avoid using the instance's attribute dictionary which may have overwritten `__instancecheck__`. Then, we should attempt to call `__instancecheck__(obj, cls)` and if it fails, then reassign obj with `obj.__class__` (again, perhaps) and keep doing it until we finally get a result.